# Opening Word document saved to the Desktop takes it straight to Print

Tags: microsoft-word, desktop

When I click to open a Word document on the Desktop, it does not open and instead goes to Print.  A little notice saying it is printing literally flashes across the document and it begins to print.  I'm using Windows 7 on an XP machine.

Comment: Does the issue only occur with the specific Word document on the Desktop? Please check other documents on the desktop and others stored on different locations. If you right click on the Word document, select Open with, pick Microsoft  Word from the list and click OK, will Word open it properly? You can also open Word first, click File > Open to open the document on desktop. If it always goes to Print when opening the specific document , are there any macros auto-running in it?

Comment: My husband's computer is using Word 97 and Office 2003.  Suddenly, a few days ago, this situation began to happen.  Any document on the Desktop does not open but goes straight to Print, with a flashing notice that goes too fast to read.  I can open Desktop docs if I open Word first.  There are no macros auto-running in the doc.  Thank you very much for trying to get me out of this fix.  Please do help.